# openjdk 8 patch version

Tags: java, jenkins, java-8, virtual-machine

I have a jenkins build job to create artifacts with latest openjdk 8 patch version which is 8u222-b10 but the VM where the build artifacts needs to be deployed is running with lower patch version(e.g. 8u141).
My Question how critical it is run build with higher patch in lower patch environment?
What should be the best practice to follow?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the patch version is not relevant with respect to building an application. It is just the runtime which might have minor changes. These changes typically include time zone changes, security bugfixes or certificate updates.

So I never had problems within the same major version. But it is always a good idea to have the runtime version executing your java program updated to the latest version.

Comment: There have been problems, but they tend to be with rather obscure functionality. For example we had a bunch of servers suddenly have trouble communicating with clients over RMI when updating the JVMs. Turned out Oracle had disabled RMI over HTTP as default in between 2 minor versions of 1.8. After some digging through the release notes we discovered that all we needed to do was add a JVM parameter to turn it on again that had in the past not been needed.

Comment: That is good to know. But what if the Build and runtime has two different minor version. Let's say Build has higher minor version and runtime has the lower version. Let me know if there is any issue.